# AWS ECS Fargate files upload without S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I want to ask about any feature that allows normal files uploads.

I tried to use the AWS EFS, but it keeps showing errors.

this is the error I'm getting:

```
ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve "fs-0d3a6954788af5d3c.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/efs/mount-dns-name for more detail. Attempting to lookup mount target ip address using botocore. Failed to import necessary dependency botocore, please install botocore first. : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 1
```

And this is the task definition in JSON

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/laravel-test",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "readOnly": null,
          "containerPath": "/var/www/storage/app/public",
          "sourceVolume": "storage"
        }
      ],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "ACCOUNTID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/laravel-s3",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "laravel-test"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:ACCOUNTID:task-definition/laravel-test:1",
  "family": "laravel-test",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.efsAuth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.efs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "runtimePlatform": {
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX",
    "cpuArchitecture": null
  },
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 1,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "transitEncryptionPort": null,
        "fileSystemId": "fs-0d3a6954788af5d3c",
        "authorizationConfig": {
          "iam": "DISABLED",
          "accessPointId": null
        },
        "transitEncryption": "DISABLED",
        "rootDirectory": "/data"
      },
      "name": "storage",
      "host": null,
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
    }
  ]
}
```

The final solution for me is to use ECS with EC2 on demand and EPS but I really want it to be without any EC2.

Is there any suggestion for me or any idea how to use the EFS without any errors?

Comment: EFS is the correct solution. You should edit your question to show what errors you are getting when you try to use EFS, and also include your task definition JSON in your question.

Comment: @MarkB could you please refer me any tutorial that could help me to achieve it

Comment: @MarkB I added the error message + task definition in JSON foramt

Comment: I have tried so many solutions and it keeps give more errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this solution and it's about defining the security group on creation

[ECS and EFS connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648722/16705502)

At the end still facing errors, I'm moving files to S3